# How to get the most recent timestamped file in BASH

Tags: bash

I'm writing a deployment script that saves timestamped backup files to a backups directory. I'd like to do a rollback implementation that would roll back to the most recent file.

My backups directory:

```
$:ls

.              1341094065_public_html_bu  1341094788_public_html_bu
..             1341094390_public_html_bu
1341093920_public_html_bu  1341094555_public_html_bu
```

I want to identify the most recent file (by timestamp in the filename) in the backup directory, and save its name to a variable, then cp it to ../public_html, and so on...

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest-timestamped filename should sort last alphabetically.  So you can then use `tail -n1` to extract it.

Comment: This is exactly what I need in this case. Thanks... oddly, this doesn't work: `mostRecentBu=ls $buDir | tail -n1` The error is `line 92: /srv/www/tmm.toomodernmedia.com/backups: is a directory`

Comment: @starsinmypockets: Your failing command says: "Launch the `$buDir | tail -n1` command, with the variable binding `mostRecentBu=ls` added to the environment. You need to enclose the whole command (from the `=` character onwards) in backticks `\`...\`` or dollar-parens `$(...)` (that is called COMMAND SUBSTITUTION). That apart from the fact that this is incorrect scripting, see my answer which will never fail.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -t` will sort files by mtime.  `ls -t | head -n1` will select the newest file.  This is independent of any naming scheme you have, which may or may not be a plus.

Answer (score 2):

...and a more "correct" way, which won't break when filenames contain newlines, and also not when there are no matching files (unexpanded glob results)

```
for newestfile in ./* ; do : ; done
if test -e "$newestfile"; then do something with "$newestfile" ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For files that don't have newlines in their names:

```
shopt -s nullglob
printf '%s\n' "$buDir"/* | tail -n 1
```